# How pipe after replace in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like a to replace characters inside a string and then split it.
Example below:

```
$in = "string with spaces"
$out = $in -replace 's' | $_.Split(' ')
```

Leads to `ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline`.

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: What do you want to replace `s` with?

Comment: Nothing, in this case `s` just gets deleted from the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the result of the replacement going *into* the pipeline, but your next step doesn't actually *read* from the pipeline. For the construct you chose you need a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$out = $in -replace 's' | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(' ') }
```

or call `Split()` on the result of the replacement (without pipeline):

```
$out = ($in -replace 's').Split(' ')
```

However, if you use the `-split` operator instead of the `Split()` method you can simply daisy-chain it (again without using the pipeline):

```
$out = $in -replace 's' -split ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$in = "string with spaces"
$out = $in -split ' '  -replace 's'
echo $out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Replace` string method instead. E.g to replace `s` with blank, and *then* split on space:

```
$out = $in.Replace('s','').split(' ')
```